# List storing matrices as characters instead of binary R

Tags: r, list, numeric

Hello I have created a list with the following loop

```
portfolio_covlist2<-list()
for (i in 1:25) {
  a<-covst[Stock.mix.2[i,],Stock.mix.2[i,]]
  a<-list(matrix(a,nrow=2))
    portfolio_covlist2[i] <- a
}
```

The data then look like this

```
[[1]]
            [,1]        [,2]
[1,] 0.009168161 0.001283940
[2,] 0.001283940 0.002723437

[[2]]
            [,1]        [,2]
[1,] 0.021906044 0.002600486
[2,] 0.002600486 0.009508103
```

I want to then be able to multiply these like

```
w2*portfolio_covlist2[1]*t(w2)
```

to give me a standard deviation of the mixes.  but I get this error:

```
Error in w2 * portfolio_covlist2[1] : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

the w vectors confirm as numeric but the list types do not...HELP!

thanks

Comment: `w2*portfolio_covlist2[[1]]*t(w2)`? If it's a list, then `portfolio_covlist2[1]` is still returning a list, with just one element in it, that happens to be your matrix. `[[1]]` returns the element itself. Try `list(1:3,2:4)[1]` versus `list(1:3,2:4)[[1]]` to see the difference.

Comment: Can you share data in a reproducible format? Something that we can copy and test it ourselves? Read about how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: OMG!!!  I don't need to store the results in a list at all.  I can create the response from a in the code and then store the results directly in a new vector!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inadvertently trying to multiply a list instead of a matrix.

And incidentally, I think you want `%*%` for matrix multiplication instead of `*` which will do element-wise multiplication.

```r
L <- list(structure(c(0.009168161, 0.00128394, 0.00128394, 0.002723437), .Dim = c(2L, 2L)), structure(c(0.021906044, 0.002600486, 0.002600486, 0.009508103), .Dim = c(2L, 2L)))

m <- matrix(1:4, nr=2)

m %*% L[1] %*% t(m)
# Error in m %*% L[1] : requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments
1
m %*% L[[1]] %*% t(m)
#            [,1]       [,2]
# [1,] 0.04138273 0.06385697
# [2,] 0.06385697 0.10079068
```

The reason is that with `list`, the `[` operator returns a list with the selected elements within it, while `[[` returns a single (not-listed) element:

```r
L[1]
# [[1]]                         <--- this means it is still in a list, even just length 1
#             [,1]        [,2]
# [1,] 0.009168161 0.001283940
# [2,] 0.001283940 0.002723437

L[[1]]
#             [,1]        [,2]
# [1,] 0.009168161 0.001283940
# [2,] 0.001283940 0.002723437
```

Comment: okay, so, you cannot output a composed matrix to a list?  So how do I create a group of 25 matrices if not In a list?  the data.frame seems wrong to me.

Comment: Huh? This *is* a `list` of matrices, and this does do the multiplication you need. The only difference is that you need `[[` vice just `[`. (Don't confuse the `%*%` operator with anything frame-like. It has nothing to do with `%>%` from `magrittr`, re-exported by `dplyr`. `%*%` is the linear-algebra matrix multiplication operator built into base R.)

Comment: OKAY!  got it.  Thanks so much.  A week ago I didn't quite get it.  But now I do.  Learning a programming language in the dark during Covid is not ideal!